# How to join two tables and use each row only once from both tables

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery

I have two tables that tracks when a user enters and leaves phone screen displays.  One table records time of entry into the display.  Another table records time they exited the display and how long they were in that screen display.  I want to pair enter-exit entries based on time (and UserID and Type).  A pair is determined a match when the exit time minus entry time is +/-1 second of the recorded duration time.  The tricky part is there may be multiple enters and/or exits that may satisfy the duration criteria.  If there are multiple enters, then take the earliest.  If there are multiple exits, then take the latest.  It’s this tricky part (the multiples) that I’m struggling with and seek assistance.

My data looks like the following.

Table: phone_enter

| UserID | Type | RecordedTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Au55 | ScreenDisplay | 10/17/2022 19:48:27 |
| Au55 | ScreenDisplay | 10/17/2022 19:48:38 |
| Au55 | ScreenDisplay | 2022-10-17 19:48:49 |
| Au60 | ScreenDisplay | 10/17/2022 16:26:55 |
| Au65 | ScreenDisplay | 10/17/2022 4:20:32 |

Table: phone_leave

| UserID | Type | RecordedTime | Extent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Au55 | ScreenDisplay | 10/17/2022 19:48:27 | 0 |
| Au55 | ScreenDisplay | 10/17/2022 19:48:29 | 2 |
| Au55 | ScreenDisplay | 10/17/2022 19:48:41 | 3 |
| Au55 | ScreenDisplay | 2022-10-17 19:48:51 | 3 |
| Au60 | ScreenDisplay | 10/17/2022 16:27:01 | 6 |
| Au65 | ScreenDisplay | 10/17/2022 4:20:39 | 5 |

This is my query (in BigQuery), which I don’t know how to modify to account for the multiple enter and multiple exit records that meet the duration tolerance criteria.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
SELECT enter.UserID, enter.Type, enter.RecordedTime as enter_time,
       leave.RecordedTime as leave_time,
       leave.Extent, DATE_DIFF(leave.RecordedTime,enter.RecordedTime,SECOND) AS DvnExtent,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY enter.UserID, enter.Type
                          ORDER BY enter.RecordedTime) rnk_enter,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY leave.UserID, leave.Type,
                                      ((DATE_DIFF(leave.RecordedTime,enter.RecordedTime,SECOND) = leave.Extent-1) OR
                                       (DATE_DIFF(leave.RecordedTime,enter.RecordedTime,SECOND) = leave.Extent+1) OR
                                       (DATE_DIFF(leave.RecordedTime,enter.RecordedTime,SECOND) = leave.Extent))
                          ORDER BY leave.RecordedTime) rnk_leave
FROM   test.phone_enter enter
JOIN   test.phone_leave leave
ON     enter.UserID = leave.UserID
AND    enter.Type = leave.Type
AND   ((DATE_DIFF(leave.RecordedTime,enter.RecordedTime,SECOND) = leave.Extent-1) OR
       (DATE_DIFF(leave.RecordedTime,enter.RecordedTime,SECOND) = leave.Extent+1) OR
       (DATE_DIFF(leave.RecordedTime,enter.RecordedTime,SECOND) = leave.Extent))
)
WHERE rnk_enter = rnk_leave
ORDER BY UserID, Type, enter_time, leave_time
```

This query returns this:

| UserID | Type | enter_time | leave_time | Extent | DvnExtent | rnk_enter | rnk_leave |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Au55 | ScreenDisplay | 2022-10-17 19:48:27 | 2022-10-17 19:48:27 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| Au60 | ScreenDisplay | 2022-10-17 16:26:55 | 2022-10-17 16:27:01 | 6 | 6 | 1 | 1 |

This is my desired result:

| UserID | Type | enter_time | leave_time | Extent | DvnExtent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Au55 | ScreenDisplay | 2022-10-17 19:48:27 | 10/17/2022 19:48:29 | 2 | 2 |
| Au55 | ScreenDisplay | 2022-10-17 19:48:38 | 2022-10-17T19:48:41 | 3 | 3 |
| Au55 | ScreenDisplay | 2022-10-17 19:48:49 | 2022-10-17 19:48:51 | 3 | 2 |
| Au60 | ScreenDisplay | 2022-10-17 16:26:55 | 2022-10-17 16:27:01 | 6 | 6 |

I could accomplish this would a loop, but it isn't performant.  SQL would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

> A pair is determined a match when the exit time minus entry time is +/-1 second of the recorded duration time.

This task can be done with `lag` and window functions.

> If there are multiple enters, then take the earliest. If there are multiple exits, then take the latest.

I miss here the information how long backwards to look for the last entry. Is a leave cancelling all entries before?

In this example we build first the entry and leave table. Then we union these and before sorting by timestamp we substract one second from the entry table. Then we apply the window functions. All calculations are done "partition by userid", thus think of each user has its own table for the following description:

The column `lag_enter_time` is the previous entry time just before the leave entry. If there was a leave before this leave, this column is null.

The last `last_enter_time` is the last entry and must be happend at maximal 100 rows before the leave one.

The `first_enter_time` is the first entry to this leave one. There is a cutoff, that the entry must be at maximum 30 seconds before this leave. But there is no limit for the entries and leaves in this timeperiod.

```sql
with enter as (
Select "Au55" as UserID,timestamp("2022-10-17 19:48:27") as RecordedTime
union all Select "Au55",timestamp("2022-10-17 19:48:38")
union all Select "Au55",timestamp("2022-10-17 19:48:49")
union all Select "Au60",timestamp("2022-10-17 16:26:55")
union all Select "Au65",timestamp("2022-10-17 4:20:32")
), leave as (
Select "Au55" as UserID,timestamp("2022-10-17 19:48:27") as RecordedTime, 0 as extent
union all Select "Au55",timestamp("2022-10-17 19:48:29"),2
union all Select "Au55",timestamp("2022-10-17 19:48:41"),3
union all Select "Au55",timestamp("2022-10-17 19:48:51"),3
union all Select "Au60",timestamp("2022-10-17 16:27:01"),6
union all Select "Au65",timestamp("2022-10-17 4:20:39"),5
),
helper as 
(Select *,null as enter from leave
union all select userID, timestamp_sub(RecordedTime,interval 1 second) as RecordedTime ,null, RecordedTime as enter  from enter)

Select *,
lag(enter) over (partition by UserID order by RecordedTime) as lag_enter_time,
last_value(enter ignore nulls) over (partition by UserID order by RecordedTime rows between 100 preceding  and current row) as last_enter_time,
first_value(enter ignore nulls) over (partition by UserID order by unix_seconds(RecordedTime) range between 30 preceding  and current row) as first_enter_time,

from helper
qualify enter is null
order by 1,2
```